# How to edit mail appearance in PHP?

Tags: php, email, appearance

I wonder how that can change the appearance of e-mail that comes to me via PHP?

[image: Here's the email:]

[image: I'd like to look something like this for example]

This is a PHP code:

```
<?php
$Ime = $_POST["Ime"];
$Prezime = $_POST["Prezime"];
$NaslovOglasa = $_POST["NaslovOglasa"];
$Email = $_POST["Email"];
$SadrzajOglasa = $_POST["SadrzajOglasa"];
$Kontakt = $_POST["Kontakt"];

if (isset($_POST['Istaknut_Oglas'])) {
$IstaknutOglas = "Da";
} else {
$IstaknutOglas = "Ne";
}

if (isset($_POST['Standardni_Paket'])) {
$StandardniPaket = "Da";
} else {
$StandardniPaket = "Ne";
}

$Za = "bratunac.info@gmail.com";
$Od  = "Od: " . $Email . "\r\n";
$Info .= "|NOVI OGLAS|" . "\r\n";
$Info .= "Ime: " . $Ime . "\r\n";
$Info .= "Prezime: " . $Prezime . "\r\n";
$Info .= "Naslov oglasa: " . $NaslovOglasa . "\r\n";
$Info .= "Sadrzaj oglasa: " . $SadrzajOglasa . "\r\n";
$Info .= "Kontakt informacije: " . $Kontakt . "\r\n";
$Info .= "Istaknut oglas: " . $IstaknutOglas . "\r\n";
$Info .= "Standardni paket: " . $StandardniPaket . "\r\n";
$Info .= "" . "\r\n";

if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
$name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];  
for($i = 1; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "adsuploads/".$name_array[$i])){
        $Info .= "Fotografija ".$i.": ".$name_array[$i]. "\r\n"; 
    }
}
mail($Za, $Od, $Info);
header("Location: http://bratunacinfo.000webhostapp.com/pages/postavi_oglas-3");
}
?>
```

I wonder if this can be done via php me or I need some framework

Comment: Use html (setting email's content type to `text/html`)

Comment: I recommend using a tried and tested mail library like SwitfMail, PHPMailer or similar for this. It's gonna save you time from reinventing the wheel. When sending html-emails, You should also add a plain text part for the email clients that can't read HTML emails or have it turned off, which is easy with one of the common libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send your email as an HTML email. For example:

```
<?php
    $to = "someone@somedoamin.com";
    $subject = "Some email title";
    $content = "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>HTML email</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
?>
```

For more information you can visit [this](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following:

1. Prepare your mail contents in html format.

   `<html>
   <body>
   //write your stuff
   </body>
   </html>`
2. Provide absolute path of your image instead of relative path. So, just providing image name is not sufficient. You need to provide exact path where that image resides in your server. So that, it will load it from there.

Comment: I already did that, everything worked well and came Recent But how to change the appearance of e-mail

Comment: I just want to when we arrive mail looks different and not just text

Comment: what do you mean by appearance ?? You need to set `Content-type:text/html`

Comment: I did a form in HTML and everything works right, or I want to email looks different when for example when sending mail youtube

Comment: @MProduction - If you want it to look different, just change the HTML markup? You're question is very very unclear!